# What is the purpose of `wire()` and `isWired()` in Seam?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, seam

I am checking out Seam 2.2.0.GA, and using `seam generate-entities` it generated `Home` classes with the methods `wire()` and `isWired()`. What are these methods and what purpose do they serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isWired()` returns a value that indicates whether the object has all its required references to other objects filled (i.e. all required (not null) foreign keys have values). `wire()` tries to fill these fields with values from the relevant `Home` objects.

(I hope someone can post a better description.)

Answer (score 1):

The server to "wire" together entity classes together.  The later version of Seam have them actually filled out.  I've never actually used them in over a year of Seam programming.